# If a matrix has rank r, show that there exists two matrices such that their product give initial matrix, both with rank r

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ a matrix with rank $r$. Proof that exist two matrices $B\in\mathcal{M}_{m,r}(\mathbb{R})$ and $C\in\mathcal{M}_{r,n}(\mathbb{R})$, both with rank $r$ such that $A=BC$.

Comment: Probably, you could use singular value decomposition? $A = U\Sigma V^T$. Since the diagonal of $\Sigma$ is non-negative, you can compute its "square root" and define $B = U\sqrt{\Sigma}$? (be careful, because $\Sigma$ is not a square matrix).

Comment: @Math The expression of $A$ as a product $A = BC$ is known as a [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization). The Wikipedia page gives two common constructions, and another common approach is to used a [reduced QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Rectangular_matrix).